When Register Component twice with same tage name globally, Then Component not rendered when webpack production build
I register componentA globally using Vue.component ( name is 'componentA' );
And create new componentB this way
<script>
// componentB.vue
import componentA from './componentA.vue';
export default {
    name: 'componentA',
    extends: componentA,
    setup(props, ctx) {
            ...componentA.setup(props, ctx)
        }
    }
}
</script>

And this component is registered by
import componentB from './componentB.vue';
delete Vue._context.components['componentA'];
Vue.component('componentA', componentB); 

Everything is Ok when build a project in development mode(webpack).
But when build a project as a production mode, then this component is not rendered.
And If componentA is a made by option api, then everything is ok in production mode.
This problem occurs only componentA is composition api.
Is there any way to solve this problem? ( ex. perfect guide of uninstall global component )
I checked more, than it's not about Vue.component
It's error about extends.
<script>
// componentB.vue
import componentA from './componentA.vue';
export default {
    name: 'componentAExtends',
    extends: componentA,
    setup(props, ctx) {
            ...componentA.setup(props, ctx)
        }
    }
}
</script>

// componentA.vue
<template>
    <div>This is ComponentA</div>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    someProps...
})
</script>

and
import componentB from './componentB.vue';
Vue.component('componentAExtends', componentB); 

and use in another component
<component-a-extends />

Then that component never rendered.
In this case, componentA is a composition API component.
But If componentA is an option API then everything is ok.
And even componentA is a composition API,
If I build using webpack development mode, then Everything is ok.
But If I build using webpack production mode, then Never rendered.
I extend component after reading this article(https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition#extends)

Is this Vue 3 in compat mode? "globally using Vue.use" - do you mean Vue.component? Needs to be debugged and probably needs a way to reproduce as this could be specific to your setup. But this looks like design problem. You should avoid registering it in the first place. What you describe looks like some kind of DI that could be implemented properly

yes, I mean vue.component.
I understand this is strange usage. But I have to override vue.component.

Please, provide a way to reproduce, this is specific to your case, it's unknown why a component isn't rendered. All that Vue.component does is adding a component to _context.components, so what you try to do could work. Also consider updating the question with what you're trying to achieve and why in case you're interested in getting a workable solution. Currently this looks like XY problem, and there could be conventional ways to do this that don't require the use of undocumented features

I append more information in article. Thanks!

componentA is not shown, please, add it. Does it use "script setup"?  The actual problem is that A's render function may not be inherited properly. Consider explaining what componentB does and what ...componentA.setup(props, ctx) is supposed to do. The solution may depend on this.

I write a componontA. ComponentA is made by "script setup". Thanks!

Then componentA.setup(props, ctx) is potentially render function instead of an instance, and you need to return it as is from B's setup to guarantee the template is rendered. It's unclear how you intended to extend A, but in case you modify the instance, this may not be possible. Consider explaining the situation in the question if you need to work around this

Thanks. I understand. But it's strange when webpack development mode, everything is oK. But this error only occurs webpack production mode. Do you have any idea about this?

Not specific to webpack, I saw this in other setups. This is how vue sfc compiler works https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/v3.5.12/packages/compiler-sfc/src/compileScript.ts#L83-L89 . This is one of many things why I'd avoid "script setup". It's not standardized, magical and not documented, you can only know from practice what happens under the hood, from my experience it saves time in 95% cases and wastes it a lot in the remaining 5. You can at least switch to setup() as a quickfix to make it work . And the way you extend could be refactored because it's hacky and looks like design problem
